# Custom Office plugin not compatible with 2016

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, outlook, outlook-addin

I am very new to programming, and recently started a job at a software company doing SQL work. Even though I was clear about my programming experience, I was assigned a task to look at our Outlook plugin because it will not install on Outlook 2016. It also will not show the plugin at all if a user had it installed previously, and upgrades to 2016. I was given the source code and told to go to town, but I'm not familiar with developing Outlook Plugins at all. To add to that issue, the prior versions of this plugin were done by a freelancer, so there is nobody here with the knowledge to be of help. On top of that, the plugin was written using Visual Studio and Visual Basic, and nobody in my office has any knowledge on either of those.

The situation is FUBAR, but I am expected to at least produce something after several weeks of working with it.

Here is what I know:

- When you try to install the plugin, it gives this [Failed Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNamA.jpg) error dialog. I am hoping beyond hope that this will be something as easy as changing a supported version list somewhere, but I have no idea what I would even change if I had that mythical list.
- I was able to use the very limited amount of coding knowledge that I have to pick out a line that refers to another file, and throws an error based off of what I understand to be a result of that file. Here is the code that I am referring to:

  ```
  Private Shared _ThisAddIn As ThisAddIn

  Friend Shared Property ThisAddIn() As ThisAddIn
  Get
      Return _ThisAddIn
  End Get
  Set(value As ThisAddIn)
      If (_ThisAddIn Is Nothing) Then
          _ThisAddIn = value
      Else
          Throw New System.NotSupportedException()
      End If
  End Set
  End Property
  ```

I'm honestly not even positive that the code above has anything to do with the problem, but the "System.NotSupportedException" caught my eye.

If anyone will let me know if there is an easy solution for this issue, I will be eternally grateful. Or if I can even be pointed in the right direction, I am not against learning about VB or Outlook plugins, I am just hitting a stopping point with what I was given.

Comment: How does the add-in "not work" in 2016?  I assume it just doesn't load?  Also, that install error may be thrown by some custom code in the installer.  Do you have the source code for the setup project?

Comment: Sorry about that, I will go back to edit and clarify. What I meant is that it simply will not install, and throws the "Supported Version" error. If someone had it installed previous to an upgrade to 2016, it simply isn't there. I would love to post all of the source code, but for legal reasons I am told I can't.

Comment: Without code snippets it will be difficult to pinpoint the problem. Have you reviewed the setup package to ascertain whether there are version dependencies that are hard-coded?

Comment: Ok, I found the class for ThisAddIn.vb which is what the earlier code was referring to. It does have an if statement that mentions Outlook2013, but I'm trying to thread together where everything else gets sent from there. I will keep looking and update this thread if I find anything. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well it looks like this will be my final update as far as this project goes, because I just learned that the entire thing was built using an MS Office tool that is incompatible with anything newer than Office 2013. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No worries. Curious though, what tool exactly?  Outlook add-ins have been my expertise for a very long time so I don't want to call it on this patient quite yet!

Comment: Well originally I was working on VS Pro 2012, and the toolset was VSTO 2005. I was told I'm allowed to download and use the 2015 version of both, so now everything is loading into the IDE just fine.
Now I'm faced with getting a password for a protected file before it will allow me to build, but that isn't something that anyone on here can help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio provides Templates for Outlook VSTO Add Ins for various versions of Outlook. 
Take the source code that you have in the current project, create a new Outlook Add In using Visual Studios templates, and place the source code within it.

This should then be compatible with everything from 2010 up.

Comment: I actually did this exact thing last night, and it works perfectly. It still won't build just yet, but that is for other reasons that don't apply here. Thanks for your input!